# Is it possible to retrieve the search term a user used programmatically on my page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm  pretty sure it isn't, unless the user clicks an Ad where I have appended a keyword parameter but some things I have read have made me wonder. Is it possible to programmatically retrieve the search term a user used on a search engine before clicking on a link to my page.

e.g. user searches "camping gear" on google, clicks an organic link to my website page. On that page can i somehow retrieve the search term via code.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: If you're posting ads through Google, it should pass that information through to you in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should look at the `document.referrer`.  If the domain of the `document.referrer` is a search engine, you can sometimes see the keyword that the user queried before clicking to your site.

Some search engines and sites block the `document.referrer` from being sent for privacy reasons.  You are out of luck in those cases.

After testing and confirming, Google (of course), blocks this information.  So when clicking a link and landing at your site, all you see in the referrer is `https://www.google.com/`.  They achieve this by using a query hash 'trick', like so: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=active&pws=1&q=Superbowl+Commercial+Bingo

Now, if you are paying for Adwords, you will see the keywords the user searched in your Google Analytics but not on your site via JS or via backend logic that either could look at the referrer.